# How to add Java sub directory to Resources directory of mac app bundle

Tags: install4j

I would like to use install4j to make it easier to deploy my Java application to Windows, Mac, and Linux.  I am evaluating install4j on my Windows development machine to make sure it can do what I need before I purchase it.

So far, I can get it to work for Windows and Linux but not for the Mac.  The Mac app bundle that I cobbled together (without install4j) currently has the following structure where the Java dir contains external jar files (such as `derby.jar`) required by my application.

```
myApp.app
  Contents
  MacOS
  Resources
    Java
```

Perhaps I can use a simpler structure but this is what I have for now and it works.  Unfortunately, the structure install4j builds does not work (it cannot find my `derby.jar`) and I cannot figure out how to get install4j to duplicate the app bundle directory structure that I know does work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The bundle directory structure is not configurable in install4j. If you have to add derby.jar to the class path, you can add it to the distribution tree and then to the class path of the launcher, like for all other JAR files. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That works fine for Windows and Linux.  Unfortunately that does not work on the Mac (at least the way I got it to work before trying to use install4j).  For some reason the class path (with the corresponding jar files in the location referenced by the class path) is not enough.  The Mac seems to need a directory with the jars in it and a corresponding entry in the info.pklist file.  I did try this with install4j but the resulting app bundle does not work on the Mac.  Of course, I am probably missing something and am willing to consider suggestions.

Comment: I would prefer hearing from somebody who has successfully deployed a Java desktop application with an embedded Derby database using install4J.  I have already successfully deployed the same without using install4j.  Thanks,